# sql update with priority base on given values

Tags: sql

I have the following carRepair table

```
car     repair  repair_date   
toyota  breaks  1/3/2018
toyota  motor   1/2/2018
toyota  brakes  1/1/2018
mazada  lights  1/2/2017
mazda   brakes  1/1/2017
```

I need to add a column that includes the car prior worst repair, base on:

worst repair

1. motor
2. brakes
3. lights

Something like this

> ```
> car    repair repair_date worst_repair
> toyota breaks 1/3/2018    motor
> toyota motor  1/2/2018    motor
> toyota breaks 1/1/2018    breaks
> mazda  lights 1/2/2017    breaks
> mazda  breaks 1/1/2017    breaks
> ```

currently I'm doing updates one by one, like:

```
 update cr set cr.worst_repair = cr2.repair 
 from 
     carRepair cr inner join 
     carRepair cr2 on 
            cr.car = cr2.car and 
            cr.repair_date >= cr2.repair_date
where
    cr2.repair = 'lights'
```

then

```
 update cr set cr.worst_repair = cr2.repair 
 from 
     carRepair cr inner join 
     carRepair cr2 on 
            cr.car = cr2.car and 
            cr.repair_date >= cr2.repair_date
where
    cr2.repair = 'breaks'
```

finally

```
 update cr set cr.worst_repair = cr2.repair 
 from 
     carRepair cr inner join 
     carRepair cr2 on 
            cr.car = cr2.car and 
            cr.repair_date >= cr2.repair_date
where
    cr2.repair = 'motor'
```

Is there a more efficient way, than doing this one-by one?

To clarify, breaks override lights, motor override all of them.

Thanks

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: This shows one of the challenges of a schema that has not been normalized.  If the repair type was in its own table with the vehicle repair using a FK, you could assign a significance value to the repair type, then get the highest significance value per vehicle, without needing to store it as a separate field.  Even if there is a better way to write the query you've requested, it is still a Band-Aid over a much larger problem with your schema.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  Which dbms is this for????

Comment: maSTAShuFu mssql

Comment: Both solutions work, and their performance is almost the same. I chose the latter because I like its syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that is extensible, using a table defining different repairs and their severities:

```
create table repairTypes (severity integer, description varchar(30));
# should make severity unique

insert into repairTypes values (1, 'lights'), (2, 'breaks'), (3, 'motor');

update carRepair cr
set worst_repair = (
  select rt.description from repairTypes rt
  where rt.severity = (
    select max(rt2.severity) as max_severity
     from carRepair cr2 
       inner join repairTypes rt2 on cr2.repair=rt2.description
     where cr2.car=cr.car
     and cr2.repair_date <= cr.repair_date
  )
);
```

Comment: -1 This solution takes a step in the right direction by trying to normalize the repair types, but does it in a bad way.  Using the severity as a unique identifier doesn't consider that some repairs may have equal severity, or new problems may need to be added which would shuffle the severity values.  Furthermore, it still makes use of a worst_repair column, when that should actually be determined by finding the repair record with the worst severity.  This doesn't go far enough to fix the original problem.

Comment: @WesH Whether it is correct to have a redundant worst_repair column is a matter that depends on how it will be used. If it is frequently queried, the complex query needed to compute it might add up to a lot of database overhead. A computed column can be a good choice when the processing required to compute it periodically is less than the cumulative processing required to query it N times over the same period. Many other factors should also be considered (e.g. it is acceptable for the value to be slightly stale, can triggers be used, etc.)

Comment: @WesH As for multiple repairs sharing the same priority, this assumes something about the business requirements that was not expressed in the question. But I agree that there are many things about the current model that should be reconsidered.

Answer (score 1):

Using TOP 1 and Outer Apply in SQL-SERVER and Order by the priority

Demo here http://rextester.com/live/UTOV54697

```
declare @carRepair table (car varchar(10),repair varchar(20), repair_date date, worst_repair varchar(20) null)

insert into @carRepair (car,repair,repair_date)
values 
('toyota','brakes','1/3/2018'),
('toyota','motor','1/2/2018'),
('toyota','brakes','1/1/2018'),
('mazda','lights','1/2/2017'),
('mazda','brakes','1/1/2017')

select * from @carRepair


update c1
set worst_repair = isnull(x.repair,c1.repair)
from @carRepair c1
outer apply (
select top 1 c2.repair
from @carRepair c2
where c2.car = c1.car
and c1.repair_date >= c2.repair_date
order by
(case c2.repair when 'motor' then 1 when 'brakes' then 2 else 3 end)
) x


select * from @carRepair
```